# How do I dynamically uniquely identify a submitted form on a single page with multiple <form> elements?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

What I am trying to do is to `hide` the `form` element when the user submits the form, and display a 'Thank You' message via AJAX.

The issue I am having is the page has at least 3 forms that look identical.

It is a `Devise` registration form too, so how do I just hide the specific one that the user submitted and not the other 2 on the page - with jQuery?

This is my form code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource), :validate => true, :html => { :id => 'user_new' }, :remote => true) do |f| %>
    <div class="six columns alpha"> 
       <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true}, :validate => true %>
    </div>              
    <div class="three columns sign-up alpha">
          <%= f.submit :label => "Submit", :value => "Sign Me Up!"  %>
      <div class="ajax-response"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
          </div>
<% end %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't

`$('#user_new').submit(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});`

Do the job?  That should hide the form on submit. While the forms look identical, they should have different ids or at the very least, classes, which you can easily reference in your jQuery.

Comment: So the way `Devise` works is I have to put my JS inside a `create.js.erb` file. As a result of that, this doesn't work - because the form has already handled the submit. Basically, I have to hide the form AFTER the submit was done - but have it be separate from the submit action (if that makes any sense). An alternative might be if there is a Rails attribute that allows me to hide it on submit, then maybe that may work - but I don't know of such an attribute.

Comment: Couple things, 1) Have you generated the form files so you can edit them? 2) I haven't fully grokked what you're dealing with here — but in situations I've run into where I've needed js to run on specific views (and only on those views) I've added a yield section in my layout that dumps javascript into the footer only when i request it in a view.

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) I am using Devise to manage user authentication. I am actually breaking Devise' forms by having 2 step authentication. So on the main page, I have 3 'enter email address' forms (the identical form in 3 diff places). So what I am trying to do is on the submit, just replace the form where they entered their email address with a 'Thank You' message - upon success.

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to achieve is...on the form that just did a submit `POST`, I want to perform some jQuery on that specific form (which doesn't have a static unique ID) and tell it to hide and display some other text.

Comment: are these forms using remote: true ? You don't want to re-render the view if you want to modify it in place!

Comment: Yes, I am using remote: true. Your solution seems to work some times, but not all the time. For instance, when the email currently exists, it submits but nothing happens on the front-end. This is what I am really trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089315/how-do-i-get-my-new-registrations-devise-form-to-be-ajaxified

Answer (score 0):

here's a demo i made that will give you a possible approach for your requirement.

[see the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/f8x3D/)

as MBHNYC stated, you will need to have unique id's for each form so it works properly.

Comment: Hrmm, I know that I need a unique ID for each form. The issue is I don't know how to generate one and properly use that particular ID - given the Rails structure (i.e. including Devise). Based on what you are suggesting, jQuery will hijack the `submit` functionality and handle it outside of the Rails form helper, right? That approach doesn't work here.

Comment: just use a class name, no need for ID's using the `this` within the submit handler

Comment: actually, you don't have to return false on the form submit. i did that for a simple demonstration on jsfiddle to allow time for an alert message to surface and validate the form id.  just eliminate return false from the code to get expected default behavior.  this way, the jquery code is already there for you.