# How do I get my new registrations Devise form to be AJAXified?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

What I want to happen is when the account is successfully created, the form that was submitted should disappear and a message should appear (depending on the status of the registration).

If it was successful, they should see a simple "Thank you. Please check your email."

If it wasn't, then they should see an appropriate message - like "Sorry, that email has already been taken."

This is my form:

```
<div class="nine columns offset-by-three sign-up-form">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource), :validate => true, :html => { :id => 'user_new' }) do |f| %>
    <div class="six columns alpha"> 
       <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true}, :validate => true %>
    </div>              
    <div class="three columns sign-up alpha">
      <%= f.submit :label => "Submit", :value => "Sign Me Up!"  %>
      <div class="ajax-response"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my `create.js.erb`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $('#user_new').submit(function() { 
    $(this).fadeOut(600).hide(); 
    $(this).append('<h3>Thank You. You should receive an email shortly.</h3>').fadeIn(1000);
  });    
)}
```

But this doesn't work properly. For instance, when I press submit and the email address is already in the db - nothing happens.

P.S. I know that if it were a 'regular' form, I would do `format.js` within the controller that is handling this form - and work out the status codes & messages there - but Devise is a different beast and I don't want to generate new controllers and override functionality that I shouldn't, when I am not fully comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

As Devise uses `respond_with` on the `Devise::Registrations` controller you should be able to use a simple AJAX call to send the form and retrieve the response. This is the simplest form that I know.

To do that, add this Javascript code to your sign up form page:

```
$("#user_new").submit(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/users",
    success: function(){
      $(this).fadeOut(600).hide(); 
      $(this).append('<h3>Thank You. You should receive an email shortly.</h3>').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    error: function(){
      // Put your error code here
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to use the create.js.erb file after the creation, you should do this:

- Add `:format => :js` and `:remote => true` to your `form_for`
- Only this code should be on `create.js.erb` file:

  ```
  $("#user_new").fadeOut(600).hide().append('<h3>Thank You. You should receive an email shortly.</h3>').fadeIn(1000);
  ```

Doing this way, Devise will execute the :js file content after AJAX response in case of success.

Comment: So put `:format => :js, :remote => true` on the form...then put that code snippet in my `create.js.erb`? Was a bit confused by the directions :|

Comment: I've rewritten the directions :)

Comment: My jQuery is clearly not right. What happens is, I still see the form - but everything fadesOut then fadesIn (almost as if it is blinking). What I want to happen is for the textbox and everything in `#user_new` to disappear and just my message re-appear.

Comment: To do what you want, do the fade out and then you insert the `'<h3>Thank You...' message after the form through the after function  and you do the fadein. To keep it after the fade out, put it on the callback.

Answer (score 0):

the way that worked for me was to

first put in `:remote => true` in the sign up form

then there are 2 options

1. to make sure that the controller where the form is repond_to :js and in the controller js file (specifically in my case it was the home action in the pages controller (pages#home) I would put in the home.js.erb something like

> ```
>  $(function() {
>       return $(".new_user").ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
>         if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
>           $("#notice").fadeIn();
>           $("#notice").html(jqXHR.responseText).fadeOut(1000);
>         }
>       });
>     });
> ```

1. the second option is to use the automatically used js file by rails/devise which is the create.js.erb which needs to be created under /views/devise/registrations. that file would be something like

> ```
>    $("#signUpForm").bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status) {
>   <% if resource.errors.full_messages.count <1 %>
>       $("#noticesignup").html("Confirmation Mail Sent :) ");
>   <% else %>
>       $("#noticesignup").html("<%= escape_javascript ( devise_error_messages!) %>");
>   <% end %>
> });
> ```

and pretty much that's it